# Java String tokens

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string line

```
String user_name = "id=123 user=aron name=aron app=application";
```

and I have a list that contains: {user,cuser,suser}

And i have to get the user part from string. So i have code like this

```
List<String> userName = Config.getConfig().getList(Configuration.ATT_CEF_USER_NAME);
String result = null;

for (String param: user_name .split("\\s", 0)){
for(String user: userName ){
    String userParam = user.concat("=.*");
    if (param.matches(userParam )) {
        result = param.split("=")[1];
    }
}   
}
```

But the problem is that if the String contains spaces in the `user_name`, It do not work.
For ex:

```
String user_name = "id=123 user=aron nicols name=aron app=application";
```

Here `user` has a value `aron nicols` which contain spaces. How can I write a code that can get me exact `user` value i.e. `aron nicols`

Comment: put the values between delimiters? if you can't modify the text, then you have to split and take averything between two tokens as value

Comment: Well you've got a fundamental problem in your data format, by the looks of it. Are you absolutely stuck with that format, or can you fix it?

Comment: Although it is possible to write a parsing method for extracting keys and values from this string, the format is ... somewhat ... broken. You should really try to ease the format. Either don't allow spaces or put quotes around the text containing spaces (which still does not work well with the split method).

Comment: @JonSkeet No the data comes from an external application and I can not change it. I have to use it anyway.

Comment: You've got good answers now, but I'm concerned about the data format... if someone *can* enter a username (or other value) with an `=` sign in it, they could cause some interesting problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet No the data comes from HP archsight. So in that case if it conains `=` in username or value it will provide us a backslash for that. So in that case regix should be different. I am really curious now. Thanks !

Comment: @CODEFISH Splitting is only one way to handle it. Directly matching is cheaper (see my answer).

Comment: @CODEFISH For the non-split solution, added a more general solution in case you're not sure whether the `name=` token follows `user`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to split only on spaces that are right before tokens which have `=` righ after it such as `user=...` then maybe add [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) condition like

```
split("\\s(?=\\S*=)")
```

This regex will split on

- `\\s` space
- `(?=\\S*=)` which has zero or more `*` non-space `\\S` characters which ends with `=` after it. Also look-ahead `(?=...)` is [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) match which means part matched by it will not be included in in result so split will not split on it.

Demo:

```
String user_name = "id=123 user=aron nicols name=aron app=application";
for (String s : user_name.split("\\s(?=\\S*=)"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
id=123
user=aron nicols
name=aron
app=application
```

---

From your comment in other answer it seems that `=` which are escaped with `\` shouldn't be treated as separator between `key=value` but as part of value. In that case you can just add [negative-look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism to see if before `=` is no `\`, so `(?<!\\\\)` right before will require `=` to not have `\` before it.
BTW to create regex which will match `\` we need to write it as `\\` but in Java we also need to escape each of `\` to create `\` literal in String that is why we ended up with `\\\\`.

So you can use

```
split("\\s(?=\\S*(?<!\\\\)=)")
```

Demo:

```
String user_name = "user=Dist\\=Name1, xyz src=activedirectorydomain ip=10.1.77.24";
for (String s : user_name.split("\\s(?=\\S*(?<!\\\\)=)"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

output:

```
user=Dist\=Name1, xyz
src=activedirectorydomain
ip=10.1.77.24
```

Comment: nice explanation. But i am curious about comment that I made on `anubhva` answer.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

First split input string using this regex:

```
" +(?=\\w+(?<!\\\\)=)"
```

This will give you 4 `name=value` tokens like this:

```
id=123
user=aron nicols
name=aron
app=application
```

Now you can just split on `=` to get your name and value parts.

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY8yT5)

#### [Regex Demo with escaped =](http://regex101.com/r/eG3rW7)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I loved it. The data comes from HP archsight. So in that case if it conains = in username or value it will provide us a backslash for that. How to handle that. I am not so good in regex.

Comment: Can you tell me a sample line then I can sure look into it.

Comment: String s = "user=Dist\=Name1, xyz src=activedirectorydomain ip=10.1.77.24"; In this the user conatins a value which has = sign and which is escaped using backslash.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain this regex? It will be good for others too, who will look into this answer in future .

Comment: Well first may I know what's wrong with this answer as you didn't accept it even though my answer was posted first.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. But now I have accepted an answer and it had good explanation. I am very sorry for this. But I seriously loved your regex demo. Looking forward to gain knowledge from you on SO. I think you will don't mind.

Comment: No I don't really care about one mark but this is not the general practice on SO. Whatever answer is correct and posted first is accepted, you are old enough on this forum to realize that. I purposely provided you my regex demo links which has detailed explanations on regex uses on bottom.

Answer (score 1):

CODE FISH, this simple regex captures the user in Group 1: `user=\\s*(.*?)\s+name=`

It will capture "Aron", "Aron Nichols", "Aron Nichols The Benevolent", and so on.
It relies on the knowledge that `name=` always follows `user=`

However, if you're not sure that the token following user is name, you can use this:

```
user=\s*(.*?)(?=$|\s+\w+=)
```

Here is how to use the second expression (for the first, just change the string in `Pattern.compile`:

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("user=\\s*(.*?)(?=$|\\s+\\w+=)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: hey nice answer but name will not always follow user. It is generated dunamically. and any field can be present after user.

Comment: I am writing this to eat my own words. Thanks zx81.

Comment: @CODEFISH You said "name will not always follow user." Hey no worries, I added a second method for that situation (also without splitting). :)